# X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM for Facebook Chat - can't connect since Oct 1st

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0, facebook-chat, x-facebook-platform

With the OAuth 2.0 and encrypted access token changes I can't connect to FB chat anymore.  The example on FB's chat document shows PHP on the server side, however I need to connect by getting the access_token from the JavaScript sdk.

I took out the sig and session_key parameters from my challenge response, and added the parameter for access_token, setting it to the access_token I get from the JavaScript sdk.  I assume the access_token is correct because before Oct 1st it had pipes in it, and now it's encrypted without the pipe symbols.  Also looking at my security settings, the xmpp_login permission is being set properly when I initially grant permissions.

No matter what I try my connection attempt fails.

Does anyone have working code where the access token comes from the JavaScript sdk in a browser rather than from the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Got it:  Make sure you're also using TLS. In the PHP code example: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ you'll see how this is handled if you search for $START_TLS